# Hierarchical structure in PostgreSQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table that contains the following structure:

```
Parent     child1     child2
1          10         12
2          13         
3
```

I want to have:

```
 Parent     child1     child2
    1          10         12
    2          13         13
    3          3          3
```

I mean, if child2 is NULL, I want to duplicate child1 into child2;
and if child1 is null, I want to duplicate the parent into child1 and child2.

Comment: `COALESCE(child2,child1,parent) AS child2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
select Parent,
       coalesce(child1, Parent) as child1,
       coalesce(child2, child1, Parent) as child2
from <tablename>;
```

?

Comment: Yeeees, it's exactly what i was looking fooor. Thank you so muchhh for your quick answers.